# How to access the object in api it changes in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Short Explaination -
There are 4 Selects every choice by ONCHANGE enabled function that brings the val into the URL of the API of Wikipedia.

The problem -
Every time I'll choose Select Another example I want to appear in the title.
wiki.query.pages [number] .title
The problem is that the number varies each time I want to access it without knowing it in advance.

```js
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <style>
 .textim {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  float: left;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<select onchange="abc()">
  <option value="israel" >Israel</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
  <option value="russia">Russia</option>
  <option value="spain">Spain</option>
</select>

<div class="textim"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function abc() {
 var ttls = $( "select" ).val()
 var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles='+ttls + "&callback=?";
 $.getJSON( url, function ( wiki ) {
  
  console.log(wiki);
 
  
  console.log(wiki.query.normalized[0].to);
  $('.textim').text( wiki.query.normalized[0].to );
  
 });
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a function, that can get object properties as a keys.

```
var getKeys = function(obj){
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in obj){
      keys.push(key);
   }
   return keys;
}
```

Then just call it, passing your object. In your case:

```
getKeys(wiki.query.pages)[0]
```

will return a number.

And to get your extract:

```
wiki.query.pages[getKeys(wiki.query.pages)[0]].extract
```

Comment: Thanks,now i want get the extract under the number

Comment: wiki.query.pages[getKeys(wiki.query.pages)[0]].extract